# How to embed an audio and a subtitle file into a MKV file

Tags: video, audio, video-editing, subtitles, matroska

I have a `MKV` file in which I want to embed an `AC3` audio file. I also want to embed a `SRT` subtitle file into it. How can I achieve that?

Note: AC3 file is the same length of the original video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have [MKVToolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) installed, you can use the `mkvmerge` command to merge together the streams.

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv -A input.mkv sound.ac3 subtitles.srt
```

The `-A` switch makes sure no sound is taken from `input.mkv`. See the [examples section](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.examples) for more.

---

For Windows, there exists the [MKVToolnix GUI](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MKVtoolnix), which would make this a little easier:

[image]

In Ubuntu and similar distros, there should be the `mkvtoolnix-gui` package.